# Merging two lists of time-series objects (ts) into a new a list

Tags: r, list, time-series

I have several lists of time-series for several countries. Is it possible to merge them while keeping a list for each country (listing all variables)?

As an example, please consider this data for one country (CHE):

```
GDP <- list(CHE = structure(c(99.8434859769227, 99.5344620742553, 97.238582764046, 
95.0831648559733, 93.0539540272435), index = c("2020-01", "2020-02", 
"2020-03", "2020-04", "2020-05"), class = "ts", .Tsp = c(2020, 
2020.33333333333, 12)))

EXPRT <- list(CHE = structure(c(21.4220407907972, 20.8542317603181, 20.9518846384104, 
17.261560042682, 16.5993061452528), index = c("2020-01", "2020-02", 
"2020-03", "2020-04", "2020-05"), class = "ts", .Tsp = c(2020, 
2020.33333333333, 12)))
```

This is what I have tried so far, resulting in a complete merge:

```
list12 <- Map(c, GDP, EXPRT)
```

Desired output would be a list with the country `CHE` list for both variables.

Comment: Desired output would be like this: library(BGVAR)

data(monthlyData)
list_ts_ex <- monthlyData

Comment: I did not add it as desired output because I was not able to reproduce it with the data for my example.

Comment: @bittomio I guess the solutions in my post would give the same format output as you showed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be we can `merge` after converting to `zoo`

```
library(zoo) 
Map(function(x, y) merge(GDP = as.zoo(x), EXPRT = as.zoo(y)), GDP, EXPRT)
```

-output

```
#$CHE
#              GDP    EXPRT
#Jan 2020 99.84349 21.42204
#Feb 2020 99.53446 20.85423
#Mar 2020 97.23858 20.95188
#Apr 2020 95.08316 17.26156
#May 2020 93.05395 16.59931
```

---

Or with `xts`

```
library(xts)
lst1 <- Filter(function(x) inherits(x, "list") && 
         all(sapply(x, inherits, "ts")), mget(ls()))
out <- lapply(do.call(Map, c(f = function(...) Reduce(merge, 
     lapply(list(...), as.xts)), lst1)), function(x) {
          colnames(x) <- names(lst1)
     x})
out1 <- lapply(out, ts, start = c(2020, 1), frequency = 12)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is almost "perfect" to me. With the merge approach, is it possible to keep variables as time-series? It's transforming them in 'zooreg'. Once again, thanks

Comment: @bttomio you can reconvert with `as.ts` or wrap with `ts`, but that will change the format

Comment: @bttomio I updated the post for the second case.  It is now `ts` class

Comment: thanks a lot. It works perfectly. Just to clarify one thing, please. The ```lst1``` object searches for all lists in my global environment?

Comment: @bttomio It is just that I loaded other objects in the environment.  So, i `Filter` only those object that are `list` and have `ts` class.  If you have only those ts objects in the env, you can durectly use `mget(ls())` to load all objects at once in a `list`

Comment: All right, got it. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear on precisely what the output should be but if we create a vector of names and use mget to get a named list of the contents then combining them as shown will give a list L and then using cbind on that to give a single mts/ts object.  This also works if nms has more than 2 elements.

If you want a list omit the the last line -- the names will be the same as shown below -- or if you want a single mts/ts object use the entire code.

```
nms <- c("GDP", "EXPRT")
L <- do.call("c", mget(nms))
do.call("cbind", L)
##           GDP.CHE EXPRT.CHE
## Jan 2020 99.84349  21.42204
## Feb 2020 99.53446  20.85423
## Mar 2020 97.23858  20.95188
## Apr 2020 95.08316  17.26156
## May 2020 93.05395  16.59931
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a nice approach, before the cbind. It keeps the data as time-series. Nevertheless, it does not list both variables under [[CHE]]. It would rather create several independent variables, without the country list.

Comment: I think you will have to better explain what you want.  What does "list both variables under [[CHE]]" mean?  Please show in the question (not in comments) the precise output that you want.

Comment: Sorry for not being precise enough. @akrun provided the answer. Thanks once again